# Programmatically changing magento product attributes values and output

Tags: product, attributes

In my store, it makes sense for us to have a single attribute for a certain variable, but on the front-end we want to divide the list. For example, a product may have the following options:

- Size 1, Type A
- Size 1, Type B
- Size 2, Type A
- Size 2, Type B

Only one of these options can be selected. In magento this shows up as a single dropdown. What we want to do is divide this into two lists and use radio buttons. For example:

Type A 
 - Size 1
 - Size 2

Type B
 - Size 1 
 - Size 2

Because only one can be selected, it makes sense to have these options in a single attribute field. How can I programmatically intercept the output so I can change the option items to radio buttons, and separate them into two lists?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box.
And I think it requires a lot of code to make this possible.
But in my opinion this is not worth it.
Magento already has configurable products.
And they cover all the cases you need an even more.
I don't know why you need to store size and type in the same attribute value when you can have them in 2 attributes.
This will solve your problem for frontend out of the box.

Also if you have 2 separate attributes you will be able to generate only a subset of possible combinations.
For example this:

- Size 1, Type A
- Size 1, Type B
- Size 2, Type A